# When $2^{2012}$ is multiplied by $5^{2013}$, what is the sum of all the digits in the product?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

When $2^{2012}$ is multiplied by $5^{2013}$, what is the sum of all the digits in the product?

I know that if the base is the same, I can add the powers, but the base is not the same, nothing matches an formula. I don't get it, I mean the only way I think I can find the answer is if I find out the value of $2^{2012} \cdot 5^{2013}$. I tried to mannually do the equation and got 5 as the anser, but in a test, I wouldnt have enough time to do the actually thing, so is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: $a^n b^n = (ab)^n$

Comment: Please consider using MathJaX to format your question. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The product is $5$ followed by $2012$ zeroes, so the sum of (decimal) digits is $5$.

Comment: Not every math problem can be solved in one step using one rule. Sometimes you need two steps (or more) each using a different rule. This one needs only two rules and you know both of them.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: you've told us that there's a rule for when bases are the same, $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$.

What's the rule for when the exponents are the same?: $a^xb^x=(ab)^x$?

Then, notice that $2^{2012}$ and $5^{2013}$ do not have exactly the same exponents, but they *very nearly* do...

You certainly *will* be able to find the value of $2^{2012}\times 5^{2013}$, even if this value is too large to actually write out.

Comment: I cant really do anything if they dont have the same power :(

Comment: @VideoGameBot why not? What does $5^{2013}$ actually mean?

Comment: @VideoGameBot Don't let the big exponents scare you. They are designed to do just that so just keep your cool. Check out what happens instead with $2^1\cdot5^2$, $2^2\cdot5^2$, $2^3\cdot5^2$ or $2^2\cdot5^3$ et cetera. Do enough small cases and you will see the light!